# PHP error failed to open stream/failed opening

Tags: php

These are the errors I have:

```
Warning: include(core/init.inc.php):
    failed to open stream: No such file or directory in test.php on line 2

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/core/init.inc.php'
    for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in test.php on line 2
```

Here is my code:

**init.inc.php**

```
<?php
$path = dirname(__FILE__);

include("{$path}/inc/csv.inc.php");
include("{$path}/inc/users.inc.php");
?>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
include('/core/init.inc.php');
?>
```

Normally I should have at this white screen, but I got all errors immediately, anyone have any idea that this could be?

I followed this tutorial on the web: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TqhSrBJHTIY (3 parts)

I think I have as in the tutorial. Yet done the same:

[image]

Comment: try to remove a leading slash from `include('/core/init.inc.php');`, let it be `include('core/init.inc.php');`, because `core` folder and `test.php` file are in the same directory

Comment: I have also the same error with this

Comment: Your files are called `.inc` and not `.inc.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the comments, your files are **not** called `.inc.php` - they're called `.inc`. That means that `init.inc.php` in fact, does **not** exist, but `init.inc` does.

[image]

You have two options:

- Rename your `init.inc` to `init.inc.php`, `csv.inc` to `csv.inc.php` and `users.inc` to `users.inc.php`
- Change your `include` statements to use `include('core/init.inc');` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Confusing: sometimes it also happens to be the name then choose name.php name.php.php will now adds that the extension is not behind.

Comment: @averroken Do you create your files in windows? Have you [enabled extensions on known files](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions#show-hide-file-name-extensions=windows-7)?

Comment: No, Always the files created with Netbeans IDE 7.4

Comment: probably through a reinstall of netbeans that my settings were disrupted.

Comment: @averroken Perhaps - it sounds weird it it'd work sometimes and not other times. With programming there's always *a reason* that a bug happens, and if you follow the exact same workflow on the exact same hardware, a bug will *always* be consistent.